# mapping from many-to-one in entity framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a `User` class

```
public partial class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
```

and this is my `Blog` class

```
public partial class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int? PostedBy { get; set; }
    public virtual User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BlogImage> BlogImages { get; set; }
}
```

and my `Image` class

```
public partial class BlogImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I need to select from `Blog` with image Name and UserName

I've created this query but I don't now how to join the `User` class:

```
var blog = _context.Blog.Include(x => x.BlogImage).Include(a => a.BlogImage).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: See following :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause :  var blog = from b in _context.Blog join bi in _context.BlogImage on b.Id equals bi.Id

Comment: Your last line of code doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
var blog = await _context.Blog
    .Select(p => new
    {
        Id = p.Id,
        Title = p.Title,
        Content = p.Content,
        PostedBy = p.PostedBy,
        UserName = p.User.UserName,
        ImageNames = p.BlogImages.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

You can also create a DTO type to hold the result you are expecting -

```
public class BlogDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int? PostedBy { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ImageNames { get; set; }
}
```

and then query like -

```
BlogDTO blogDTO = await _context.Blog
        .Select(p => new BlogDTO
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Title = p.Title,
            Content = p.Content,
            PostedBy = p.PostedBy,
            UserName = p.User.UserName,
            ImageNames = p.BlogImages.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
        })
        .ToListAsync();
```